# Atom doesn't recognize classes imported from another file -- python

Tags: python, atom-editor

This is a beginner question but I am using Atom and when I create classes in one file and then import those classes using `import file_containing_classes` to use them in another file it only sees one of the classes? Does it have something to do with `__pycache__`. Even after I run the file save the file, the python script that imports the file with classes doesn't recognize it.

Suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any plugins for atom installed?

Comment: a few - I have atom-ide, hydrogen and some others. Any in particular that might be causing issues?

Comment: Rather lack of one. I haven't used atom for a while, but as far as I remember it does not recognize symbols properly. I'd try to find some decent python plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue has something to do with the fact I have hydrogen installed, once I ran the code like a hydrogen notebook it seems to have worked.